# How do I import and monkey patch a Python module that is in a different package from the tests?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-import, monkeypatching

My source tree looks like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── flask_main.py
│   └── lib.py
├── run_endpoint_check_tests.sh
├── run_flask.sh
├── run_unit_tests.sh
└── tests
    ├── endpoint_checks.py
    └── test_lib.py
```

`flask_main.py` (naturally) imports `lib.py` like this:
`import roku_lib`

But to get `test_lib.py` to import `lib.py`, I need to do this:

```
sys.path.append("app")
from app import lib
```

And I run the unit tests using this (in `run_unit_tests.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
python -m pytest
```

(I haven't been able to get running `pytest` to work, which I guess makes sense after reading https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code.)

This unit test fails though:

```
def test_load_from_s3(mocker, monkeypatch):
    x_mock = mocker.Mock()
    return_mock = mocker.Mock()
    x_mock.Object = mocker.Mock(return_value=return_mock)
    monkeypatch.setattr(lib, 'get_x', lambda: x_mock)

    y = lib.get_x()

    x_mock.Object.assert_called_once()

    ...
```

I think it fails because calling lib.get_x() results in it importing it's own (copy of?) lib that is not monkey patched.

The same test works when the source tree looks like this:

```
    .
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lib.py
    ├── uses_lib.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test_uses_lib.py
        └── test_lib.py
```

And `sys.path.append("app")` & `from app import lib` are unnecessary.

But for historical reasons, I *must* keep `flask_main.py` in the app package. I could move `lib.py` into a separate package though, if that solves my problem.

So finally my questions...

How do I fix the imports or monkey patching code (or both) so the monkey patch works?

Is it possible (by adding extra empty `__init__.py` files where missing, perhaps?) to get the import to work in `test_lib.py` *without* `sys.path.append("app")`?

Comment: trying using pycharm running pytest, but I think you need to make a common parent module (for app and tests) from where you can access the module like, `from parent_module.app import lib`  instead of `from app import lib`, and way 2. create a new python module in main directory which do functionality like `flask_main.py` and set it as flask app

Comment: Let's say the parent directory is named `proj`. If I put a `__init__.py` in it, would `from proj.app import lib` work from the tests? I'll try it.

Comment: #2 is not an option. And I need the unit tests to run from the command line, so an IDE isn't a complete solution. Thanks.

Comment: plus a little change (i like to suggests) is add your server file (FLASK_APP) in the main directory not in app [see sample  structure](https://ideone.com/VLV6EN), also to run the test do `python -m pytest tests/test_<file_name>.py` keep python execution path same as the `main_app.py`

Comment: Because I'm porting an existing app from Python 2 to 3, moving flask_main.py is not an option.

Comment: what you can do is import flask app constructor (`app = flask(__name__)`) from `<parent dir>/app/flask_main.py`  to `<parent dir>/main_app.py` as `from app.flask_main import app \n new_app = app` and  set this `main_app` to `flask_app`, nothing to change rest of code and this thus enable your `app` module in other modules apart from `app`

Comment: I think I may understand the core of what you're getting at, but re-reading the above comment is not making it more clear. Perhaps you could clarify by making it an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: I think I found a solution...move `lib.py` to a `libs` directory, and import it from both the `apps` and `tests` directories using `sys.path.append("..")` & `from libs import lib`. I'll create an answer if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214693/discussion-between-sahasrara62-and-daryl-spitzer).

Answer (score 0):

I moved `lib.py` into a `libs` directory:

```
.
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── flask_main.py
├── libs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib_a.py
│   └── lib_b.py
├── run_endpoint_check_tests.sh
├── run_unit_tests.sh
└── tests
    ├── endpoint_checks.py
    ├── test_lib_a.py
    └── test_lib_b.py
```

(And I split `lib.py` into `lib_a.py` and `lib_b.py`. `lib_b.py` imports `lib_a`.)

And I import `lib_a.py` and `lib_b.py` the same way in `flask_main.py`, `lib_b.py`, and `test_lib_a.py` & `test_lib_b.py`:

```
sys.path.append("..")
from libs import lib_a
from libs import lib_b
```

Now `flask_main.py` runs properly *and* the unit tests pass (with the monkey patch assertions not failing).

Note I deleted `run_flask.sh` since I now have to run `flask_main.py` with the `app` directory as the cwd.

Note also I still have to run `python -m pytest`——running `pytest` leads to ModuleNotFoundErrors.